# IBM Worklight - Trouble with project build

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I have two issues:

1. I can not export .apk file
2. I can not understand why there is an error (see below), although the project is being compile and run on the server

[full size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Qsnv.png)
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**How to export as .apk**

Worklight does not export the generated Android project to an .apk. For this you need to use the ADT plug-in provided by Google (which I see you already have installed).

Exporting an .apk comes in two flavors: debug mode and production mode.
To understand this concept, review the following documentation by Google:

- http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

The general steps are:

1. Right-click on the generated Android project
2. Choose Android Tools > Export Signed Application Package or Export Unsigned Application Package.
3. Follow the wizard

**Error in project**

This error as well, is not related to the generation of the Android project by Worklight. This error means that you are building the application with a certain API Level (in this case 18), but this API Level is not installed in your Android SDK.

Review the following documentation by Google:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

To fix the error:

1. Open the Android SDK and select the appropriate API Level to install.
2. Right-click the generated Android project > Properties > Android > Target Platform
3. Change to API Level 18